# How to set initial value and range in easyui-datebox

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I have a `easyui-datebox` while accessing it, prompt the date form `jan 1970`
how can i make them to show current date initially (ie) is there anything like `setInitialDate()` also how can i set the date range like `setStartDate()` and `setEndDate()`

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem reported here : [JQuery easyui and Datejs date conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16558852/830945) . 
When you are using Date.js with easyui, this problem occurs. If you remove Date.js from web resources, opening a datebox would automatically show current date at first popup. Workaround for it, is using following code after initiating date field.

```
$('#dateDuetxt').datebox({
    value: (new Date().toString('dd-MMM-yyyy')) /* Date.js toString function to convert date into format that is being used by datebox. */
});
```

Complete sample code is :

```
Due Date <input id="dateDuetxt" class="easyui-datebox" style="width:100px"/>  

<script>

$('#dateDuetxt').datebox({
    value: (new Date().toString('dd-MMM-yyyy')), /* Date.js toString function to convert date into format that is being used by datebox. */
    formatter : function(date){
        return date.toString('dd-MMM-yyyy');
    },
    parser : function(s){
        var t = Date.parse(s);
        if (!isNaN(t)){
            return new Date(t);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

However, if you remove Date.js from your page, no scripting would be required, simply creating a datebox

```
Due Date <input id="dateDuetxt" class="easyui-datebox" style="width:100px"/>
```

would do the trick.